# Does User.IsInRole lookup in Active Directory each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, windows-authentication

In our MVC 5 web application we are using User.IsInRole() function to evaluate if current logged in user (with Windows Authentication) is part of respective group in Active Directory. On my local this function was evaluating quickly, but on production it is taking some time. Does this function hits Active Directory each time and looks if user is part of group?

#### Scenario:

Suppose I am having total 10 groups configured in database, and I want to get list of groups user is member of. So I am iterating 10 groups and calling User.IsInRole("group_name") and preparing expected list of groups. Does this will hit Active Directory each time to check membership of user in the group?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills - Updated my scenario, I hope this will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same question and I am investigating this for a vendor which wants to add AD auth to their SW. The short answer: yes and no :-)

The long answer: I've analyzed `WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole`

It does not query AD (via LDAP) for the group memberships, but instead uses the group SIDs in the Kerberos Token and checks if a group's SID is contained in the ticket. So for that, it does not hit AD, but:

If you use `IsInRole(string)`, it does a Name ==> SID lookup (using win32 LsaLookupNames2() call).

So, it is recommended to first translate the group name to a SID and then use the SID only:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak3kd03(v=vs.110).aspx

*For performance reasons, the IsInRole(SecurityIdentifier) overload is recommended as the preferable overload for determining the user's role.*

I haven't checked this yet, but I'm going to do this next time.

I hope to find the time to do a benchmark (checking ~40 groups in an enterprise AD with > 100K objects with this method). 
But this could take a week or so.

Please inform me if you are interested in test result.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please share your test results I am very much interested in those... thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, I am going to do some testing. I am on vacation next week, but I'll continue this soon. Stay tuned :-)